# roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'

Tags: ros

This error message appears every time I try to use `roscd` and I have used `$catkin_make` every time. It works for the working terminal but e=when I open new terminal and try the same command again the error message appears again

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://answers.ros.org/question/271053/roscd-no-such-packagestack-beginner_tutorials/